# sudo dpkg error - blank line in value of field 'Maintainer'

Tags: dpkg

I am running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and am trying to install NX. When using a `sudo dpkg` command for the plugin (`nxplugin_3.5.0-6_i386.deb`) I get an error.

I have tried a number of things. Other packages seemed to work but not this one. I have looked around quite a bit and it sounds like it might have something to do with the `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file but all I see in Line 6 of that is:

```
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
```

Here is the error:

```
sudo dpkg -i nxplugin_3.5.0-6_i386.deb
dpkg: error processing nxplugin_3.5.0-6_i386.deb (--install):
 parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/control' near line 6 package 'nxplugin':
 blank line in value of field 'Maintainer'
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nxplugin_3.5.0-6_i386.deb
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks,

Jeff

Comment: Where did you download the deb file from?

Comment: what is your architecture 64bit or 32?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily edit the Control file to work around this. Open `gedit` or `nano` and type or paste:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then
  echo "Syntax: $0 debfile"
  exit 1
fi

DEBFILE="$1"
TMPDIR=`mktemp -d /tmp/deb.XXXXXXXXXX` || exit 1
OUTPUT=`basename "$DEBFILE" .deb`.modfied.deb

if [[ -e "$OUTPUT" ]]; then
  echo "$OUTPUT exists."
  rm -r "$TMPDIR"
  exit 1
fi

dpkg-deb -x "$DEBFILE" "$TMPDIR"
dpkg-deb --control "$DEBFILE" "$TMPDIR"/DEBIAN

if [[ ! -e "$TMPDIR"/DEBIAN/control ]]; then
  echo DEBIAN/control not found.

  rm -r "$TMPDIR"
  exit 1
fi

CONTROL="$TMPDIR"/DEBIAN/control

MOD=`stat -c "%y" "$CONTROL"`
vi "$CONTROL"

if [[ "$MOD" == `stat -c "%y" "$CONTROL"` ]]; then
  echo Not modfied.
else
  echo Building new deb...
  dpkg -b "$TMPDIR" "$OUTPUT"
fi

rm -r "$TMPDIR"
```

Same the file as `debedit.sh`, and make it executable with `chmod +x debedit.sh`.

Then, run `debedit.sh nxplugin_3.5.0-6_i386.deb` for the file, and edit the correct line (or add it). Save, and then run `sudo dpkg -i nxplugin_3.5.0-6_i386.deb.modified.deb` (the name may differ a bit), and enjoy!

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=636724

Comment: Thanks FOSS, That worked for me. Quite a re-education. Just a couple of notes for those that may hit this snag too. I had to mod the 777 the permissions of the folder I was working from with the nxplugin file and script. The name DID differ. In the script it is named modfied (no I) instead of modIfied. Simple stuff once you know what works or if you are more familiar than me, but easy to miss. Once I got the nxplugin_3.5.0-6_i386.deb file  to edit and save (./debedit.sh nxplugin_3.5.0-6_i386.deb) , just put a space and period in all blank lines and esc + wq! and it ran. Thanks very much! Jeff

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the package is broken (technical: the `control` file is invalid). Maybe you could ask the author of the package to fix it.

Comment: Hi Florian, I am afraid that might be the case, I have used this and an older version before. Does this mean that there is a change it the package rules? I will check with the author but I could find no one else reporting this so I thought it might be something else. Any other way around going back to the vendor?